# Copy/paste VS Clone

Tags: design-patterns, copy-paste

When managing lists or objects, what are the advantages of a "clone" action over "copy & paste", if any?  What are the disadvantages?  Or when should you use one pattern over another?

I assume a clone action would:
 1. Automatically duplication an object in a list
 2. Increment the name to something like "Object 1 copy"
 3. Automatically enter the edit state/mode for the object in the list to allow the user to make changes.  From there a user can cancel or save the changed object?

Thanks.

Comment: I have yet to see the action terminology "Clone" used in a website. "Create Copy" or simply "Copy" should suffice for most people. Are you trying to appease regular users or is this a very technical application where people would be more apt to understand clone in the given context?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus makes a good point - I have seen clone before, but most often the term in UI is *Duplicate* (clone is more popular in programming - you *clone* an object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy and paste were originally intended to act between **two containers** (folder A, folder B).

Clone, on the other hand, is **within-container**.

Copy and paste are **two actions**, clone is **one action**. So if the **user intention** is to clone, why make this a two-action process when you can do with one?

Then:

> 1. Automatically duplication an object in a list

Indeed

> 2. Increment the name to something like "Object 1 copy"

This depends - in some systems the label is unique, in others it isn't (all TODO lists I know of allow you to put *milk* twice).

> 3. Automatically enter the edit state/mode for the object in the list to allow the user to make changes.

This is nearly always useful with textual items (not always so for graphical ones); it all depends what the list is for and what the user needs are.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of copy/paste, as I see it, is that I've been trained to type cmd-C cmd-V to make a copy of something. The only way Clone would be more efficient than that would be if it had its own keyboard shortcut and if I memorized it.